# How to detect the status of the capslock in linux programmatically

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, x11, wayland

I want some way to know if the Capslock is active or not, thought I can use `xet` for this purpose, using pipe, by `popen('xset -q | grep Capslock')` I am able to find out, but I want some way by which there is no use of the commands, in the C program, is there any way to know this.
One more thing I want to ask in this context, `xset` doens't work in the console mode in linux, I do <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> then login there and if try to run `xset -q` this will throw error, perhaps this can't communicate with the XWindows in console, so what solution can be for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want some way to know if the Capslock is active or not

You probably want [`XkbGetIndicatorState`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XkbGetIndicatorState.3.html). For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

/* Compile this with -lX11 */

int main ()
{
  Display *display;
  Status status;
  unsigned state;

  display = XOpenDisplay (getenv ("DISPLAY"));
  if (!display)
    return 1;

  if (XkbGetIndicatorState (display, XkbUseCoreKbd, &state) != Success)
    return 2;

  printf ("Caps Lock is %s\n", (state & 1) ? "on" : "off");
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can go with the [same approach that is used in xset](https://github.com/freedesktop/xorg-xset/blob/master/xset.c#L1323) and use [`XkbGetNamedIndicator`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XkbGetNamedIndicator.3.html) which is a more general function.

Answer (score 2):

Download the source to `xset` and see how it does things. It's not black magic. It will give you the functions to call to get/set the things you want. For `xset` to work, it must be invoked *under* the Window manager, so it can't be done from a VT console.

For the VT, from `man 2 ioctl_console`, you can use the `KDGKBLED` and `KDSKBLED` ioctls to get/set the flags.